# Physical and logical replication slots on Postgres (same time)

Tags: replication, postgresql-9.6, master-slave-replication

I wonder if it's possible to have a setup when changes from a single Postgres master streamed to two (or more) replicas same time, but some replicas to use streaming (logical) replication and some to use physical replication?

So far I have only seen examples of how to use one of those, but not both same time?

I'm currently on Postgres 9.6, but might upgrade, if required.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you managed to find a solution? Thank